# Got "ORA-01008: not all variables bound" from a sample query (Oracle APEX)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I entered the following to the APEX

```
INSERT INTO hr.departments 
       (department_id, department_name, location_id)
VALUES     (&department_id, '&department_name',&location);
```

That's from the powerpoint. I got the following error:

> ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Can someone please explain and why it got that error? Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct PL/SQL syntax looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO hr.departments 
       (department_id, department_name, location_id)
VALUES     (:P_DEPARTMENT_ID, :P_DEPARTMENT_NAME, :P_LOCATION);
```

where `:P_DEPARTMENT_ID`, `:P_DEPARTMENT_NAME`, and `:P_LOCATION` are names of page items or application items.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just copying and pasting from an example and trying to get it to run, it looks like the middle variable is an actual string (contained in quotes).  Wouldn't you at least want to make sure all your VALUES are one way or the other (all variables or all strings)?

Comment: Sorry! The lecture that I have doesn't display the results for this example. I was trying to see what would happen for that query since I won't get it without seeing the results. But I'll make sure of that next time!